# How do I setup a VS solution with more than one Git project in Team Services?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I am starting a new application.  The application code will live in its own Git repository in team services and it will reference another supporting library project which also lives in its own git repository in team services.  How do I setup a team services repository such that I can develop on each project and commit changes to their respective projects when cloned to Visual Studio. I keep the commits separate.

I fear such a setup might confuse Git or Visual Studio.

Here's my solution structure:

- My Solution

  - My Application Project

    - File.cpp
    - File2.cpp
  - My Supporting Library Project

    - File.cpp
    - File2.cpp

Comment: Why is there a vote for close?  I am beginning to wonder if Quora is trying to sabotage SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **git submodules** to achieve it, but you can’t view the structure directly in VS, you can view `My Supporting Library Project` in file explorer. Detail steps as below (most operations are used git command line):

1.Clone the current git repo (use VS or git command line).

2.In the local repo `My Solution` folder, use git command line (such as git bash) to add a submodule for current repo in `My Solution` folder by `git submodule add <URL for library git repo>`.

3.Commit & push changes to current git repo

4.If you want to make changes for the submodule and push them into the library git repo, you can use

```
cd <submodule folder> 
git commit 
git push
```

5.If you want to make changes for the submodule and push them into current git repo, you can commit/push by VS or git command:

```
cd .. 
git commit 
git push
```

Comment: What is the point of GIT if it can't do such a basic and common operation without such convoluted steps?  Subversion did this without much thought and it worked. Using GIT is like performing brain surgery on your own mother.

Comment: Actually the direct command is `git submodule add <URL for library git repo>`. Since it have two repositories here, so you need to pay attention commit/push in the right repo. So I listed the different workaround here.